# Is it possible to separate login functionality and its template from the ng-view directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building an AngularJS application with angular-ui-router to handle my routing.

I'm wondering if it's possible to seperate the login functionality and it's template completely from the ng-view directive, so the rest of my layout isn't shown before the user have been authenticated.

This is the current setup:
[image: 1]]

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah using Ui-Router declare create a different state like this :

```
 .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/login.html',
          })
 .state('stateNameIfLoggedIn', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            controller: 'DifferentController',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/differentTemplate.html',
            userLoggedIn: true
          })
```

In your `LoginController` check if the user is currently login redirect him to different state like this:

```
//controller code starts
if(userLoggedIn === true){
  $state.go('stateNameIfLoggedIn')
}
```

Comment: I have the configuration in my app.routes, but this will not seperate the login template from the ng-view. You would still have the entire layout shown when hitting the login state.

Comment: With Ui-router you need to use ui-view directive instead of ng-view directive to create nested states.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that with the routeProvier before show the route with the template + controller you can check something and then control the route.

```
'use strict'

intranet
.config ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider
    .when '/page1',
      templateUrl: 'views/page1.html'
      controller: 'Page1Ctrl'
    .when '/page2',
      templateUrl: 'views/page2.html'
      controller: 'Page2Ctrl'
    .otherwise
        redirectTo: '/'
.run ($rootScope,Token,$location) ->
  $rootScope.$on '$locationChangeStart', ->
    Token.check()
    $rootScope.active_menu = $location.path()
```

My token provider with check the token.

```
'use strict'
intranet
.provider 'Token', ->
  @$get = ($location,$http,$q,$rootScope) ->
    check: ()->
      if localStorage['access_token']
        $rootScope.loginMade = true
      else
        $rootScope.loginMade = false
        $location.path '/login'
```

And that's my index for show or not the content.

```
 <header-app></header-app>
    <sidebar-app></sidebar-app>
    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
      <div ng-view="" class="container" ng-class="{container_login : loginMade == false}">
      </div>
      <footer-app></footer-app>
```